# pyramid how to setup api middleware?

Tags: python, pyramid, wsgi

I've been digging into pyramid, and I'am looking to setup a middleware to serve my api.
I've done this with werkzeug using the DispatchMiddleware.

How can I achieve this within pyramid

```
project
 | __init__.py
 | api
 | | __init__.py
 | web
 | | __init__.py
```

project/api/**init**.py

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)

    config.include('cornice')
    api_includes(config)
    config.scan() // scan only api_includes/routes

    app = config.make_wsgi_app()

    return app
```

project/web/**init**.py

```
def web_includes(config):
    config.include('project.posts', route_prefix='/post')

def main(global_config, **settings):
     """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
     """
     config = Configurator(settings=settings)
     config.include('pyramid_chameleon')
     config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)

     web_includes(config)
     config.add_route('home', '/')
     config.scan() // only web_includes/routes
     app = config.make_wsgi_app()

     return app
```

project/**init**.py

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator

from api import main as api_main
from web import main as web_main

from pyramid.wsgi import wsgiapp, wsgiapp2


def main(global_configs, **settings):
    web = wsgiapp2(web_main(global_configs, **settings))
    api = wsgiapp2(api_main(global_configs, **settings))


    config = Configurator()
    config.add_view(web, name='/')
    config.add_view(api, name='api')


    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

when accssing my api, it works but going to web routes they do not work unless i specify a name that is not '/' or '' for example:

```
config.add_view(web, name='foo')
```

going to /foo or /foo/post works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
config.add_route('api', '/api/*subpath')
config.add_route('default', '/*subpath')

config.add_view(web, route_name='default')
config.add_view(api, route_name='api')
```

Using URL dispatch should enable you to mount things a little bit more simply at prefixes within the application. Routes in URL dispatch are matched in order, so make sure the api one goes before default, or everything will be sent to the default route.